# NPE when trying to run the sample treasuryYield module in mongo-hadoop

Tags: mongodb, hadoop

i installed mongo and hadoop now trying to run the sample treasuryYield app that comes with mongo-hadoop package.   when i launch it i get a NPE,  can't figure out where the issue is...

## ./gradlew --debug historicalYield

```
14:23:49.330 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: STARTING
14:23:49.331 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Waiting until process started: command '/root/hadoop-binaries/hadoop-2.4.0/bin/hadoop'.
14:23:49.335 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: STARTED
14:23:49.335 [INFO] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Successfully started process 'command '/root/hadoop-binaries/hadoop-2.4.0/bin/hadoop''
14:23:49.336 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner] waiting until streams are handled...
14:23:51.800 [ERROR] [system.err] 14/07/30 14:23:51 INFO util.MongoTool: Created a conf: 'Configuration: core-default.xml, core-site.xml' on {class com.mongodb.hadoop.examples.treasury.TreasuryYieldXMLConfig} as job named 'TreasuryYieldXMLConfig'
14:23:53.645 [QUIET] [system.out] OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /root/hadoop-binaries/hadoop-2.4.0/lib/native/libhadoop.so which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
14:23:53.646 [QUIET] [system.out] It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
14:23:53.646 [ERROR] [system.err] 14/07/30 14:23:53 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
14:23:53.702 [ERROR] [system.err] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
14:23:53.703 [ERROR] [system.err]       at java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom(Native Method)
14:23:53.704 [ERROR] [system.err]       at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.setClass(Configuration.java:1968)
14:23:53.704 [ERROR] [system.err]       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.setOutputFormatClass(Job.java:823)
14:23:53.705 [ERROR] [system.err]       at com.mongodb.hadoop.util.MongoTool.runMapReduceJob(MongoTool.java:184)
14:23:53.706 [ERROR] [system.err]       at com.mongodb.hadoop.util.MongoTool.run(MongoTool.java:93)
14:23:53.706 [ERROR] [system.err]       at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
14:23:53.707 [ERROR] [system.err]       at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
14:23:53.708 [ERROR] [system.err]       at com.mongodb.hadoop.examples.treasury.TreasuryYieldXMLConfig.main(TreasuryYieldXMLConfig.java:52)
14:23:53.708 [ERROR] [system.err]       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
14:23:53.709 [ERROR] [system.err]       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
14:23:53.710 [ERROR] [system.err]       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
14:23:53.710 [ERROR] [system.err]       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
14:23:53.711 [ERROR] [system.err]       at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
14:23:53.856 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: FAILED
14:23:53.857 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Process 'command '/root/hadoop-binaries/hadoop-2.4.0/bin/hadoop'' finished with exit value 1 (state: FAILED)
14:23:53.859 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':historicalYield'
14:23:53.859 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :historicalYield FAILED
14:23:53.860 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :historicalYield (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 5.048 secs.
14:23:53.860 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[main,5,main]] finished, busy: 15.814 secs, idle: 0.006 secs
14:23:53.865 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
14:23:53.867 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
14:23:53.868 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
14:23:53.868 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Where:
14:23:53.869 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Build file '/opt/hadoop-2.4.1/t/git/hadoop.Connector/mongo-hadoop/build.gradle' line: 498
14:23:53.870 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
14:23:53.870 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
14:23:53.871 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':historicalYield'.
14:23:53.871 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > Process 'command '/root/hadoop-binaries/hadoop-2.4.0/bin/hadoop'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
14:23:53.883 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
14:23:53.884 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
14:23:53.885 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':historicalYield'.
14:23:53.886 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
14:23:53.886 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
14:23:53.887 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
14:23:53.888 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
14:23:53.888 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
14:23:53.889 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
14:23:53.889 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
14:23:53.890 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
14:23:53.891 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
14:23:53.891 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:289)
14:23:53.892 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
14:23:53.892 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
14:23:53.893 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
14:23:53.894 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
14:23:53.894 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:86)
14:23:53.895 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
14:23:53.895 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
14:23:53.896 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
14:23:53.896 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
14:23:53.897 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
14:23:53.898 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
14:23:53.898 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
14:23:53.899 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:166)
14:23:53.899 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
14:23:53.900 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
14:23:53.900 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
14:23:53.901 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
14:23:53.902 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
14:23:53.902 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
14:23:53.903 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
14:23:53.903 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
14:23:53.904 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
14:23:53.904 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
14:23:53.905 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:174)
14:23:53.906 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:170)
14:23:53.906 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:139)
14:23:53.907 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
14:23:53.907 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
14:23:53.908 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:46)
14:23:53.908 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
14:23:53.909 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:37)
14:23:53.909 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
14:23:53.910 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
14:23:53.910 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
14:23:53.911 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
14:23:53.911 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:127)
14:23:53.912 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:55)
14:23:53.912 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/root/hadoop-binaries/hadoop-2.4.0/bin/hadoop'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
14:23:53.912 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:365)
14:23:53.913 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecAction.execute(DefaultExecAction.java:31)
14:23:53.913 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFileOperations.exec(DefaultFileOperations.java:176)
14:23:53.913 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.exec(AbstractProject.java:875)
14:23:53.913 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.DefaultScript.exec(DefaultScript.java:188)
14:23:53.914 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.ProcessOperations$exec.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
14:23:53.914 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at build_3gqj2hjrmv8igls4fb2jkjrq4h.hadoop(/opt/hadoop-2.4.1/t/git/hadoop.Connector/mongo-hadoop/build.gradle:498)
14:23:53.914 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at build_3gqj2hjrmv8igls4fb2jkjrq4h$_run_closure22.doCall(/opt/hadoop-2.4.1/t/git/hadoop.Connector/mongo-hadoop/build.gradle:433)
14:23:53.914 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$ClosureTaskAction.execute(AbstractTask.java:502)
14:23:53.915 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$ClosureTaskAction.execute(AbstractTask.java:483)
14:23:53.915 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.TaskStatusNagger$1.execute(TaskStatusNagger.java:77)
14:23:53.915 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.TaskStatusNagger$1.execute(TaskStatusNagger.java:73)
14:23:53.915 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
14:23:53.916 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
14:23:53.916 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        ... 46 more
14:23:53.916 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
14:23:53.916 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger]
14:23:53.917 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED
14:23:53.917 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger]
14:23:53.918 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] Total time: 30.005 secs
```

Answer (score 0):

run `./gradlew clean jar historicalYield`

Comment: Are you using the latest `master` code?  Those line numbers don't line up with what I have.